# Word2vec saved model is not UTF-8 encoded but the sentence input to the Word2vec model is UTF-8 encoded

Tags: python-3.x, utf-8, nlp, gensim, word2vec

I trained a word2vec model using gensim package and saved it with the following name.

```
model_name = "300features_1minwords_10context"
model.save(model_name)
```

I got these log message info. while the model was getting trained and saved.

```
INFO : not storing attribute syn0norm
INFO : not storing attribute cum_table
```

Then, I tried to load the model using this,

```
from gensim.models import Word2Vec
model = Word2Vec.load("300features_1minwords_10context")
```

I got the following error.

```
2017-06-22 21:27:14,975 : INFO : loading Word2Vec object from 300features_1minwords_10context
2017-06-22 21:27:15,496 : INFO : loading wv recursively from 300features_1minwords_10context.wv.* with mmap=None
2017-06-22 21:27:15,497 : INFO : setting ignored attribute syn0norm to None
2017-06-22 21:27:15,498 : INFO : setting ignored attribute cum_table to None
2017-06-22 21:27:15,499 : INFO : loaded 300features_1minwords_10context
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-25-9d90db0f07c0> in <module>()
      1 from gensim.models import Word2Vec
      2 model = Word2Vec.load("300features_1minwords_10context")
----> 3 model.syn0.shape

AttributeError: 'Word2Vec' object has no attribute 'syn0'
```

Also, in the file "300features_1minwords_10context", it shows that

```
"300features_1minwords_10context" is not UTF-8 encoded
Saving disabled.
Open console for more details
```

To fix the above attribute error, I have also tried the following from the google forum,

```
import gensim
model = gensim.models.KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format("300features_1minwords_10context")
model.syn0.shape
```

It resulted in another error which is

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x80 in position 0: invalid start byte
```

The model is trained with UTF-8 encoded sentences. I am not sure why is it throwing this error ?

More info :

```
df = pd.read_csv('UNSPSCdataset.csv',encoding='mac_roman',low_memory=False)
features = ['MaterialDescription']
temp_features = df[features]
temp_features.to_csv('materialDescription', encoding='UTF-8')
X = pd.read_csv('materialDescription',encoding='UTF-8')
```

Here, I had to use 'mac_roman' encoding in order to access it using pandas dataframe. Since the text in the dataframe has to be in UTF-8 while training the model, I have saved that particular feature in a separate csv file by encoding it with UTF-8 and later, I have the accessed that particular column.

Any help is appreciable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using the latest gensim? If not, be sure to try it – there have sometimes been `save()`/`load()` bugs in older versions.

The INFO "not storing" log lines are normal – they're not indicative of any problem (and thus could be deleted from your question.)

Are you getting the "has no attribute" error directly upon the `load()`? (A full error stack here would be useful, and clarify this.)

---

**UPDATE:** From the now-shown error-stack, the error is *not* occurring in the `load()` line, but on the following line, when you attempt to access `model.syn0.shape`. Recent versions of gensim no longer have a `syn0` as a property of Word2Vec class objects – that info is moved to a constituent `KeyedVectors` object, in the `wv` property. So `model.wv.syn0.shape` is likely to access what you're seeking, without an error.

---

When your model is largish, `save()` can generate multiple files on the side, with extra extensions, for the model's large array properties (like `syn0`). These files must be kept alongside the main filename for the model to be re-`load()`ed. Is it possible you've moved the `300features_1minwords_10context` file, but not any such accompanying files, to a new location where the `load()` is then incomplete?

You can't `load_word2vec_format()` a file that was native-gensim `save()`d – their different formats entirely, so the encoding error is just an artifact of trying to read a binary Python pickle file (from `save()`) as another format entirely.

Comment: Hi @gojomo, I am using latest gensim. Yes, I am getting  " has no attribute" error directly upon the load()


I have attached the error stack in the question. Nothing like syn0 is generated. Even model saved file does not have anything in it. I guess the model is not saved at all because of Unicode issues. 


And when I print the sentences, I did not get the unicode symbol like this u'Airtel'

Comment: See update inline above; the actual error isn't in `load()` but in your own next line's attempt to access `model.syn0` – which tries to access `syn0` where (in recent gensim versions) it no longer exists, having moved to `model.wv.syn0`.

Comment: Hi @gojomo, please try this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44740161/how-to-preserve-number-of-records-in-word2vec